# How can I use R to get confidence intervals in Azure ML?

Tags: r, azure, machine-learning, regression, azure-machine-learning-service

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077884/can-azure-calculate-confidence-interval-for-regressions/38115484#comment66660633_38115484) question which asks *if* Azure ML can calculate confidence - or probabilities - for row data prediction. However, given that the answer to that question is `No`, and suggests to use R, I am trying to figure out how to use R to do exactly this for a regression model.

Does anyone have any suggestions for references on where to look for this?

My scenario is that I have used Azure ML to build a boosted decision tree regression model, which outputs a `Scored Label` column. But I don't know regression analysis well enough to write R code to use the outputted model to get confidence intervals.

I am looking for any references that can help me understand how to do this in R (in conjuncture with Azure ML).

Comment: Most of us R-users don't use MS Azure ML. For me it's because I figure they will jack up the price as soon as they have an established user base. (MS has screwed me before.) If you want an R answer you will need to produce code and show what sort of R objects you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a straight forward way to compute the confidence interval from the results of the Boosted Decision Tree model in Azure ML.

Here are some alternate suggestions:

1. Rebuild the model using the library(gbm) http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/gbm/html/gbm.html or the library(glm) https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/glm.html
2. Then build the confidence interval using confint function: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/confint.html
3. For a linear model, the confidence interval computation is simpler: http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/simple-linear-regression/confidence-interval-linear-regression